# iframe does not display secured https url in IE but works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, iframe

I need to display an external secured https url in my website in an iframe.
it works in all other browsers but not in ie. I tried weather.com and it display but not the url I am trying to load.

Below is my iframecode :

```
<div>
    <iframe id="iframestyle" name="iframe_sch" runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px;
        width: 100%; height: 750px; margin-bottom: 0px; position :relative;" 
        onclick="return iframestyle_onclick()" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: It display in ie but only from certain profiles whicn I have created iframe in javascript instead of html element. below is my code :  <script type="text/javascript">
        function setiframe(url) {           
            var iframe2 = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe2.src = url;
            iframe2.setAttribute('width' , '1000');
            iframe2.setAttribute('height', '1000');
            iframe2.setAttribute('display', 'block');
            iframe2.setAttribute('align', 'middle');

Answer (score 0):

This is just a long shot hear I too find myself making mistakes on the tiniest (I should know better) scenarios lol. That being said....could it be "mixed activity"? Meaning....If the protocol of your page is http than use a http page inside the iframe.
If the protocol of your page is https than use a https page inside the iframe. Bc mixing the two can commonly cause blocking on different areas. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You for the response, but the url of the page I need to display within the iframe is not in my control, I mean its from a third party vendor to show a report based on the parameters I pass, all i can do is just pass my parameters to the url to display it.